# Python dropbox related error message meaning

Tags: python

I'm getting the error message:

```
plugin com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon interrupted

2015-02-02 22:39:01.965 Python[xxxxx:xxxxxxx] Hub connection error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application." (connection to service named com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon) UserInfo=xxxxxxx {NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon}
```

while running a program that doesn't interface with dropbox.

What does it mean?